# Extension function wrapped inside class

Tags: function, kotlin, overloading, extension-methods, operator-keyword

The following example shows a class for a shopping list item, which can be multiplied to change the amount. To be able to multiply it from either side, I need an operator function for the `ShoppingListItem` class and the `Int` class.
I don't like, that the extension function of the class `Int` is not part of the `ShoppingListItem` class, because it is logically connected with it. Any ideas how to wrap it inside?

```
data class ShoppingListItem(val name: String, val amount: Int = 1) {
    operator fun times(num: Int) = ShoppingListItem(this.name, this.amount * num)
}

operator fun Int.times(item: ShoppingListItem) = ShoppingListItem(item.name, item.amount * this)


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val myItem = ShoppingListItem("Apple")
    println(myItem)     // ShoppingListItem(name=Apple, amount=1)
    println(myItem * 2) // ShoppingListItem(name=Apple, amount=2)
    println(3 * myItem) // ShoppingListItem(name=Apple, amount=3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't place it inside the class - that would make it a [member extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members) that you can only call inside the class.

The best you can do here is to place the data class and the extensions that belong to it in the same file.

Comment: Would it then be of better style, to list all operator overloads outside the class like this:  
`ShoppingListItem.operator fun times(num: Int) = ShoppingListItem(this.name, this.amount * num)`

Comment: That part of the code organization is entirely up to you - do whichever one looks better for you.